# Soundcloud Smart Player

Tags: api, embed, html5, video-player

I have a lyrics website on WordPress with thousands of lyrics, and I am looking to embed a player on each one. But I have realised it would be tedious and time consuming to do that.

How would I display a dynamic audio player that would find and play a track (using the current post title) from soundcloud?

This could preferably be a html5 audio player or an actual soundcloud embed.

The way it plays out in my head is to do a search, then pass the first result (track url) into a variable, then call the variable in the src part of the player.

Comment: What does you currently title / url structure look like? A soundcloud link consists of two parts {author}/{track} - https://soundcloud.com/djmambo/free-dj-mix-q104-7-christmas-gift-mix-2015-by-dj-splyce so you might need more than just the title.

Comment: Hi @jgraup, I have noticed that soundcloud uses the track ID for embeds. Here is an example: `<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/216846955&amp;color=00aabb"></iframe>`

Comment: It just seems like whatever you do, pulling an ID or username from title seems like it could easily break.

Answer (score 1):

If a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) isn't too much effort you can use it to construct the soundcloud url for embedding.

```
add_shortcode('soundcloud_auto', 'soundcloud_auto_shortcode');

function soundcloud_auto_shortcode($atts) {
    global $post;

    $title = str_replace(" ", "", $post->post_title);
    $title = str_replace("-", "", $title);
    $title = str_replace("_", "", $title);

    $slug = sanitize_title($title, str_replace("-", "", $post->post_name));

    return wp_oembed_get(esc_url("http://soundcloud.com/$slug"));
}
```

Or do something similar using [the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) hook.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'add_soundcloud');

function add_soundcloud($content){
    global $post;

    $title = str_replace(" ", "", $post->post_title);
    $title = str_replace("-", "", $title);
    $title = str_replace("_", "", $title);

    $slug = sanitize_title($title, str_replace("-", "", $post->post_name));

    return $content . wp_oembed_get(esc_url("http://soundcloud.com/$slug"));
}
```

The [API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide) might be a cleaner route.